# How to convert Feb 19, 2015,22:19:50 to 2/19/2015 22:19:50 in C#?

Tags: c#, string, datetime

How can I convert `Feb 19, 2015,22:19:50`  to `2/19/2015 22:19:50` in C#?

I have tried something like below

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("Feb 19, 2015,22:19:50",
                                        "MMM dd, yyyy;HH:mm:ss",
                                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But I got following error

> A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, your string and format doesn't match *exactly*. In your string, you have a comma between your years and hours, but in your format you have a semicolon. When you have a custom parsing with `DateTime.ParseExact` or `DateTime.TryParseExact` methods, your string and format must match exactly based on `IFormatProvider` you use.

After you parse your string correctly, you can format it with `.ToString()` method wih `M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss` format and a culture that have `/` as a `DateSeparator` and `:` as a `TimeSeparator` like `InvariantCulture`.

```
string s = "Feb 19, 2015,22:19:50";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "MMM dd, yyyy,HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
   Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
   // 2/19/2015 22:19:50
}
```

Here a <kbd>[demonstration](https://ideone.com/wBsOyk)</kbd>.

Comment: @Indu If it is the correct answer so mark this as the answer so other people may have this problem will find the answer.